# Getting the error "Failed: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with"

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

While trying the click the element as:

```
element.all(by.repeater("condition in filterCtrl.conditions")).get(1).click();
```

I am getting the error as:

```
Failed: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with".
```

How I can overcome this.

My CSS is as below

```
<div class="_md-select-menu-container _md-active _md-clickable" aria-hidden="false" id="select_container_198" style="display: block; left: 764px; top: 181px; min-width: 234.547px;"><md-select-menu class="ng-scope _md-overflow" style="transform-origin: 101.273px 72px 0px;"><md-content>
<!-- ngRepeat: condition in filterCtrl.conditions --><md-option ng-repeat="condition in filterCtrl.conditions" value="CONTAINS" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-ink-ripple" aria-selected="false" role="option" id="select_option_257"><div class="_md-text ng-binding">Contains</div></md-option><!-- end ngRepeat: condition in filterCtrl.conditions -->option ng-repeat="condition in filterCtrl.conditions" value="ENDS_WITH" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_261"><div class="_md-text ng-binding">Ends with</div></md-option><!-- end ngRepeat: condition in filterCtrl.conditions -->
</md-content></md-select-menu></div>"
```

Comment: The error is very clear I guess? Why do you need to "click" the element? If you want to do something with that element, why not do it directly in your function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the pop-up opened before clicking the element. Handled this by clicking the URL, so that the pop-up gets closed and so protractor can interact with the element.

Answer (score 1):

Well the error is telling you that element isn't currently visible, so that's why it can't perform the click.  Not sure how your app is setup, if it's Angular or not etc.  But I would suggest trying 2 things:

1) If that element is definitely loaded, try to scroll it into view.

```
var scrollIntoView = function () {
    arguments[0].scrollIntoView();
}
browser.executeScript(scrollIntoView, yourwebelement);
```

**OR**

2) Make sure that element is actually present and displayed on the page.  If you change your code to an `expect` statement and add`.isPresent()` or `.isDisplayed()` - Does that return true?  Based on your error I would guess `isPresent()` returns **true**, but `isDisplayed()` returns **false**.  If that's the case try adding an implicit wait function to wait for the element to load before trying to click on it.